# how to connect external libraries in Kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy, networkx

When you try to build the application. Application normally collected and only runs if there is no outside application libraries. When you attempt to connect networkx library. Appendix normally gather. But when you try to run directly on the device. Pops saver "Loadind ..." and the application falls. What you need to change to get everything working.
Attached is the application code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import *
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
import networkx as nx


G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1)
G.add_node(2)
G.add_node(3)
G.add_node(4)
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,3)
G.add_edge(3,4)
G.add_edge(2,3)

class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        b = BoxLayout()
        l = Label(text=str(nx.shortest_path(G,1,4)))
        textinput1 = TextInput(text=str(nx.shortest_path(G,1,4)))
        textinput1.bind(text=l.setter('text'))
        f = FloatLayout()
        s = Scatter()
        s.add_widget(l)
        f.add_widget(s)
        b.add_widget(f)
        b.add_widget(textinput1)
        return b


 if __name__ == "__main__":
     SimpleKivy().run()
```

Comment: im sure you need a dll for the target device or python only modules ...

Comment: What you should have done as the first thing is `adb logcat` and check the output. There (and in kivy log directly too) you'd see the `networkx` package is missing. P4A/Buildozer packages only the default interpreter(+ kivy deps) + explicitly provided packages, so you need to state them in .spec file.

Comment: changed .spek no difference, the application still crashes

Answer (score 2):

In your `buildozer.spec` file, line `39` add your third-party requirments.

```
requirements = kivy,networkx, # or what ever
```

Comment: Seems like pure python package, so... up you go! ^^